# A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle / has not been defined

Tags: websphere, websphere-commerce

I am getting following exception when trying to launch a store using Websphere commerce

```
A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle / has not been defined
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle localhost:80 has not been defined.
```

I have tried this,

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.esupport.doc%2Fhtml%2FDevelopment%2Fswg21230161.html

and this

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iicdoc/v1r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.iic.doc%2Fts_installwgvh.html

but no use still getting error and unable to launch store(tried to launch store via Accelerator too).

What should I do to make it work properly?

Comment: Error should be directed to IBM Software Support.

Comment: As far as I know commerce has the following url: https://localhost:8000/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ConsumerDirect/index.jsp , so there is nothing on / thats why you have webgroup not defined. Try to use full commerce url.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are accessing your store either via http server or you have changed default web container port. Go to admin console `Environment > Virtual hosts > defautl_host` (or host that is mapped to your module if different) > Host aliases. Add new alias `*:80`. Restart the server.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

-Access the WebSphere Application Server Administrative Console

-go to Applications -> Applications Types -> Websphere Enterprise Applications

-choose WC module from main screen

-then go to Virtual Hosts

-most cases the "WC_default_host" will be defined for all sub modules, make sure of that, 
if that is the case and still is not working, try to choose "default_host" for all sub modules and then save changes and restart.

I faced that problem once, and this way I have fixed it in my case.

Comment: See if this might be of help. http://www.buggybread.com/2013/07/error-srve0255e-webgroupvirtual-host-to.html

Comment: I've run into this a few times thanks to my own forgetfulness (oro stupidity, whatever you want to call it). If you've ever "refreshed" your workspace, like I have to do at work, by deleting/replacing projects, grabbing HEAD and then pulling in a branch to merge your changes, then that process probably removed the Application from your Web Server in RAD. You just need to right-click the WAS server in the "Servers" tab and hit "Add/Remove" then re-publish...

Answer (score 1):

If you having the message "WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /yourwebmodule has not been defined" for some reason in your app Virtual host has not been defined

You can access the WebSphere Application Server Administrative Console

```
1ST Select : View -> All tasks
GOTO Applications -> Applications Types -> WebSphere enterprise applications
THEN click on application that having the problem and go to -> Virtual Hosts
```

Now you can see your Web module and a drop down in "Virtual host"

```
Select your Virtual host and save
```

A work around is to:

```
GOTO Environment -> Virtual hosts -> default_host
```

and use for Host Name (*) in the port that
you are using and save, check if the option saved.

If for any reason you can't save, a web server is off line and can't synchronize settings.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue by temporarily disabling my Antivirus. So you may also want to check your antivirus settings and if possible temporarily disable it.

Answer (score 0):

...or you may not have the webapp deployed at all. It is a quite common error message that I encounter when I try to access a Rest Api on the App while I have it undeployed! Please make sure you get it up before you try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the web.xml file I did revert ( Team | Revert ) with the old file everything worked again.
Probably WebSphere generated a default web.xml which made the application stop working.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31151088)

Answer (score -1):

SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle localhost:80 has not been defined.
I have deployed an application and generated pulgin and propagated also. when I acces with webserever I'm getting above error.

Sol: I have gone through all the setps what I've  performed , finally I found that my I forget to start my appliction.

I have started my application and now able to access .