# jhipster - create front end only

Tags: generator, jhipster, yo

I am trying to generate a jhipster application but i only want the frontend .... the command I am running is

```
jhipster --skip-server --auth jwt
```

The error i get it

```
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ERROR! When using skip-server flag, you must pass a database option and authentication type using --db and --auth flags
    at Environment.error (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:157:40)
    at module.exports.error (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:1488:18)
    at module.exports.validateSkipServer (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\client\index.js:159:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:418:27)
    at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\run-async\index.js:25:25
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\run-async\index.js:24:19
    at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:419:13)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:637:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Immediate.setImmediate (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:427:22)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:637:19)
```

But i dont want a DB at all i just need a nice front end application

Comment: Then why use JHipster? Use the [Angular CLI](https://angular.io/cli) to build the client app directly.

Comment: The generated client has a menu for database depending on which db you select for backend. Why don't try and see what's generated ?

Answer (score 1):

Ive just tried with --db sql,
then changed path in webpack.common.js SERVER_API_URL: 
working fine.
So this key says what db is on your backend,  and yes, it's confusing.

Comment: I create a backend proyecth ans it is runing in http://localhost:8081 and I set the propertie , like   SERVER_API_URL: `http://localhost:8081/` inside the file , but I See SRVE0255E: No se ha definido un host WebGroup/Virtual para manejar /.

Comment: This is error from the WebSphere.  Not sure how you have it running the frontend.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357822/a-webgroup-virtual-host-to-handle-has-not-been-defined